# Root access required for CUDA?

Tags: cuda, root

I am using GeForce 8400M GS on Ubuntu 10.04 and I am learning CUDA programming. I am writing and running few basic programs. I was using cudaMalloc, and it kept giving me an error until I ran the code as root. However, I had to run the code as root only once. After that, even if I run the code as normal user, I do not get an error on malloc. What's going on?

Comment: Did you also compile the code as root that one time? Maybe you needed to get your file permissions updated before the compiler was able to overwrite your binary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably due to your GPU not being properly initialized at boot.  I've come across this problem when using Ubuntu Server and other installations where an X server isn't being started automatically.  Try the following to fix it:

Create a directory for a script to initialize your GPUs.  I usually use `/root/bin`.  In this directory, create a file called `cudainit.sh` with the following code in it (this script came from the Nvidia forums).

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/modprobe nvidia

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then

    # Count the number of NVIDIA controllers found.
    N3D=`/usr/bin/lspci | grep -i NVIDIA | grep "3D controller" | wc -l`
    NVGA=`/usr/bin/lspci | grep -i NVIDIA | grep "VGA compatible controller" | wc -l`

    N=`expr $N3D + $NVGA - 1`
    for i in `seq 0 $N`; do
        mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia$i c 195 $i;
    done    

    mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c 195 255

else
    exit 1
fi
```

Now we need to make this script run automatically at boot.  Edit `/etc/rc.local` to look like the following.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#   
# rc.local
#   
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#   
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#   
# By default this script does nothing.

#
# Init CUDA for all users
#   
/root/bin/cudainit.sh

exit 0
```

Reboot your computer and try to run your CUDA program as a regular user.  If I'm right about what the problem is, then it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To work with Ubuntu 14.04 I followed https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/699610/linux/334-21-driver-returns-999-on-cuinit-cuda-/ to add `nvidia-uvm` to `etc/modules`, and to add a line to a custom udev rule.  Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-nvidia-uvm.rules` with this line:

```
KERNEL=="nvidia_uvm", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/bin/mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c $(grep nvidia-uvm /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0;'"
```

I don't understand why `sudo modprobe nvidia-uvm` works to create a proper `/dev/nvidia-uvm` (as does `sudo cuda_program`) but the `/etc/modules` listing requires the udev rule.